# how to update multiple records in core data using swift 3.0

Tags: core-data, swift3, nsurlsession, insert-update

I have a json file through which I want to insert json variables into core data 
 - I have Parsed json
 - Called Insert function to save data 
 - called fetch function to display data

- to avoid repeated entries i applied delete query before parsing .

  - but functionally it is wrong as every time view is loading all records are getting parsed and inserted .
  - so that I want apply update query but dont know , how.

below is my json file

`"Data": [
    {
      "NID": 9,
      "NoticeType": "General",
      "NoticeDetails": "Test notice to all school",
      "NoticeTitle": "Test notice to all school",
     },
    {
      "NID": 6,
      "NoticeType": "General",
      "NoticeDetails": "Notice to all school tset purpose",
      "NoticeTitle": "Notice to all school tset purpose",
       },
    {
      "NID": 5,
      "NoticeType": "General",
      "NoticeDetails": "Test to all school",
      "NoticeTitle": "Test to all school",
    },
    {
      "NID": 4,
      "NoticeType": "General",
      "NoticeDetails": "notice  to all test",
      "NoticeTitle": "notice  to all test",
    },
    {
      "NID": 3,
      "NoticeType": "General",
      "NoticeDetails": "Test notice for all",
      "NoticeTitle": "Test notice for all",
    }
  ]`

Below is my code for parsing, insertion and fetch Data

```
                    let responseJson = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as! [String : AnyObject]


                    if let dataArray = responseJson?["Data"] as? NSArray
                    {
                        for i in 0..<(dataArray as AnyObject).count
                        {
                            let jsonObjectInLoop = dataArray[i] as! [String : Any]


                            let NIDObject = jsonObjectInLoop["NID"] as! Int32
                            print("Print NID Object from json loop \(NIDObject)")

                            let noticeType = jsonObjectInLoop["NoticeType"] as! String
                            let noticeDetail = jsonObjectInLoop["NoticeDetails"] as! String
                            let noticeTitle = jsonObjectInLoop["NoticeTitle"] as! String

                            let naFileNameString = ""

                                DatabseManager.sharedInstanceOfDatabase_Manager.insertNoticeFunc(nid_p: NIDObject , noticeType_p: noticeType , noticeDetails_p: noticeDetail , noticeTitle_p: noticeTitle)



                        }

                        self.fetchNotice()
                        DispatchQueue.main.async()
                        {
                                //code
                                self.DetailsTableView.reloadData()
                                self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()
                        }




                    }


                }
////

func insertNoticeFunc(nid_p: Int32, noticeType_p: String, noticeDetails_p: String, noticeTitle_p: String)
    {

        //Insert Data
        let contextVar = appDelegateShared.persistentContainer.viewContext
        let noticeDetailContext = NoticeDetails(context: contextVar)

        noticeDetailContext.nid = nid_p

        noticeDetailContext.noticeType = noticeType_p
        noticeDetailContext.noticeDetails = noticeDetails_p
        noticeDetailContext.noticeTitle = noticeTitle_p

        appDelegateShared.saveContext()

    }



/////

 func fetchNotice() -> Void
    {
        let contextVar = appDelegateShared.persistentContainer.viewContext

        //Fetch Data
        do
        {
            let fetchCoreData = try contextVar.fetch(NoticeDetails.fetchRequest())
            let noticeResult = fetchCoreData as! [NoticeDetails]

            print("notice result count \(noticeResult.count)")


            for notice in noticeResult
            {


                //Store Id's in NSUserDefault
                UserDefaults.standard.set(notice.nid, forKey: "nID_key")
                UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

                print("NID from Core data \(notice.nid)")
                self.noticeIDArray.append(notice.nid)

                self.dateArray.append(notice.noticeDate!)
                self.noticeTitleArray.append(notice.noticeTitle!)
                self.imageUrlArray.append(notice.imageUrl!)
                self.noticeDescArray.append(notice.noticeDetails!)
                self.postedByArray.append(notice.postedBy!)

            }
            //print("Date Array : \(self.dateArray)")
        }
        catch
        {
            print("Error in fetch notice")
        }
    }
```

I have searched a lot but i am not able to found proper solution .
please provide any solution if possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not receive unique persistent IDs from backend then the only way is to delete all the entries and then insert new ones.

In your case it might seems that you are getting `NID` as a unique identifier. That means you may fetch the entry from database or create a new one if it does not exist:

```
let noticeDetail: NoticeDetails = {
    if let existing = NoticeDetails.fetch(nid: myNID) {
        return existing
    } else {
        return NoticeDetails.createNewEntry()
    }
}()
... insert data to noticeDetail...
```

Then I assume some may be deleted so you have 2 situations. First server may return a value `deleted: true/false` and if it is deleted try fetching it from database and deleting it.

In your case it seems you do not have this luxury so you need to check which are missing in the array. So unless you are worried about memory it is best to first just fetch the whole table and in the end delete the entries that were not in the new response:

```
var allDetails: [NoticeDetails] = NoticeDetails.findAll() // Get all details
// Iterate through parsed JSON response objects
myDetailDictionaries.forEach { item in 
   // Extract the unique identifier
   if let myNid = item[NID] as? String { 
      let noticeDetail: NoticeDetail = {
         if let (index, detail) = allDetails.enumerated.filtered { $0.nid == myNid }.first {
            allDetails.remove(at: index) // Remove the found object from the array
            return detail
         } else {
            return NoticeDetails.createNewEntry() // Create a new object
         }
      }()
   }
}
// Now allDetails consist only of objects that were not collected by the new response. So these need to be deleted.
allDetails.forEach { $0.deleteFromDatabase() }
```

Alternatively you can look into constraints for core data which allows you to define which fields need to be unique and setting it to NID will merge the entries so that there will only be uniques. But that does not solve deletion, nor would I suggest it for multiple reasons.